# Bootstrap labels as progress bars

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I would like label colors to have width defined as a percentage. Any css experts out there that knows if what I want is actually achievable?

```
// Bootstrap label css:

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em
}
.label-success {
  background-color: #18bc9c;
  color: #ffffff;
}

// HTML

<span class="label label-success">games</span>
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Comment: use something like: http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm with http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/ . Combine them and you should have it!

Comment: @MadsLundeland have your tried anything? SO is not free coding service.

Comment: I have tried a couple of things, but I could not figure out how to deal with variable tag length, i.e. length is determined by the tag text.

Comment: Almost there. But display: inline breaks it.. http://jsbin.com/IBOwEPog/399/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2be9a7742658fd5e5da6

With a little help of my friend javascript :)